# Can't Open Htop over SSH (Terminal Issue)

Tags: centos, ssh, manjaro, lxd

I'm connecting to a remote server through SSH Manjaro machine with urxvt to a LXD container, which is running Centos 7. But for some odd reasean I cannot run htop.....
I'm getting the following error

```
[someuser@Proxy ~]$ htop
Error opening terminal: xterm-256-color.
```

I'm pretty sure it is a terminal issue. I just don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I think this is the same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788402/error-opening-terminal-xterm-256color

Comment: I think your correct! I found the answer which is to add `export TERM=xterm` in `.bashrc`. But due to the rules I can't add the answer so quickly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `TERM` variable has a wrong value for `htop`.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788402/error-opening-terminal-xterm-256color) answer you have to set `TERM` correctly:

```
export TERM=xterm-color
```

or

```
export TERM=xterm
```

You can put this in `.bashrc` of the SSHD server user.

Comment: Easy points to you ;)

Answer (score -2):

Probably is missing the $DISPLAY environment variable or your connection through ssh-server don't allow ForwardX11, please review this parameter in the sshd.conf of your remote server.

The parameter **ForwardX11** must be **yes**

Comment: No, the question is about a terminal program, not about a GUI program.